# What is the approximate value of a Spanish ducat in 1557?

Tags: spain, spanish-empire, money, conquest

In the text of ["**A narrative of the expedition of Hernando de Soto into Florida published at Evora in 1557**"](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/34997/34997-h/34997-h.htm) the anonymous author states that de Soto "... gathered a hundred and four score thousand ducats together..." from his adventures in Peru with Pizarro.

I've been doing a bit of google research, but I can't find anything that approximates that value of a Spanish ducat at that time. Also, the text makes reference to Rials, so I would also be interested in that valuation as well.

I understand there is no way to provide an exact number. I'm looking for an approximate number: Is there any historical evidence that a Spanish ducat of that era must contain X weight of gold (or silver)?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/9j3j1z/approximate_value_of_a_spanish_ducat_in_1557/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lifting the contents of the very helpful [link provided by @gvk](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267848230_Fiat_Money_in_17th_Century_Castile) into an answer:

Source: *Fiat Money in 17th Century Castile*, by François R. Velde, Federal Reserve Bank of Chicago, and Warren E. Weber, Federal Reserve Bank of Minneapolis and University of Minnesota.

Footnote 1 states:

> The ducat disappeared as a coin in 1537 but remained as a unit of account, representing 375 maravedis.

Table 2 *Castilian monetary system, ca. 1590 (before the onset of [vellón inﬂation](https://wiki.mises.org/wiki/Vellon_inflation_in_Spain))* lists the following in the column "Purchasing Power":

- 4 *maravedis* -- 1/2 lb bread
- 15 *maravedis* -- 1 bottle wine
- 50 *maravedis* -- 1 spring chicken
- 80 *maravedis* -- 1 day skilled labor
- 200 *maravedis* -- 1 ga. olive oil
- 350 *maravedis* -- 1 bushel wheat
- 1450 *maravedis* -- minimum weekly middle class income

So 1 *ducat* was the rough equivalent of 1/4 the *minimum weekly middle class income*. It would have bought you four and a half days of skilled labor. Or 7 (live!) chickens, a bottle of wine and a pound of bread. *¡Buen provecho!*

Comment: So the "a hundred and four score thousand ducats" equates to 67,500,000 maravedis or just over 895 years of minimum middle class income.

Comment: @SteveBird: Quite a treasure. (I was not 100% sure about what number "a hundred and four score thousand" was supposed to be, and decided not to add that total to the answer in case I got it wrong. ;-) )

Comment: Downvoted "not useful" without even leaving a comment? Seriously?

Comment: +1, but if you had value for any of the nobles' income or state expenditure those would be quite nice to see as well as a 'better' (obviously debatable) point of comparison.

Comment: @gktscrk: The source has no quotable numbers to that effect; also I think that everyday commodities give a much better idea of "worth" than a nobles' "income" (which varies depending on the estate owned, obviously), or state expenditure (which is even more variable and depending on external influences than the common market). So I'm somewhat reluctant to go digging for those numbers; I think it's not really worth the effort.

Comment: So, the weekly middle class income was 18.125 days of skilled labor? What did they to gain this money, working 60 hours a day or working in superskilled tasks? The middle class income assumes 2.8 workers? :) I can't relate these two measurements.

Comment: @Rekesoft: Keep in mind the many shifts in prices, and definitions of "middle class", that have taken place between then and now. "Middle class" quite literally meant the class in the middle between laborers and nobility: merchants, landowners, the like. At a time where even skilled labor was comparatively cheap, I don't have problems picturing the middle class having three times the income of a worker.

Comment: @DevSolar Aha. Ok, so medieval "middle class" would be something like today's "upper middle-class", more or less. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks for expanding my quick comment into a helpful answer. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: @DevSolar: That's a fair point. I personally find the most "interesting" comparisons exactly that while in the 1860's the Prince of Wales's income was £100k, the Dukes of X's lands (only) brought him £180k per annum. For me, the greater access we have to all goods has reduced their value more than the the price has been naturally inflated (very debatable, however, and perhaps just wrong...). Personal points of view...

Comment: "Middle class" is an anachronism due to inappropriate research on the part of the quoted author. That author fell into the trap of poor comparisons over time. This answer doesn't.

Comment: The **vellón inﬂation** was already underway for over two generations by 1590, and had run nearly half its course.